# Multiple inputs using subprocess.run in Python 3.7+

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, subprocess

Suppose I have a python script called input_test.py:

```
first_name = input()
print(name)
```

From another python script called main.py, I can run input_test.py as follows:

```
import subprocess
file = home_dir + "input_test.py"
result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, file], input="Dan", capture_output=True, text=True)
```

This works really well for my purposes. Sometimes, though, I may require multiple inputs. Suppose we have input_test2.py:

```
first_name = input()
last_name = input()
print(first_name, last_name)
```

How do I pass two inputs (or potentially more) using subprocess.run? If that's not possible, is there a way to do this within python? As an aside, I'm working in Windows 10 inclusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I pass two inputs (or potentially more) using subprocess.run?

The `input` function stops reading when it receives a newline character...so you just need to separate your inputs with newlines:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['python', 'names.py'], input='Joe\nBiden\n', capture_output=True, text=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['python', 'names.py'], returncode=0, stdout='Joe Biden\n', stderr='')
```